# Odds ratio and Risk ratio disagree?

Tags: odds-ratio, relative-risk

Is it possible for the odds ratio and the risk ratio for a variable to disagree? For example - an odds ratio >1 and risk ratio <1?

Answer (score 3):

For a simple 2-by-2 table that is not possible. Once you have regression models behind the estimates that could easily happen.